# Конференция с премодерацией

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.

У меня возник вопрос. Мне необходимо сделать некоторую real-time конференцию с премодерацией.
Необходимо, чтобы:
1. У премодератора в реальном времени появлялись на экране заданные вопросы, присланные с сайта. 
2. Модератор мог бы либо редактировать, либо публиковать заданные вопросы. 
3. Затем эти вопросы в реальном времени отображались на экране у выступающего.

Имеется база данных MySQL, количество вопросов ожидается, что-то порядка 200-300 в час.
Что вы можете посоветовать? Как лучше это сделать? 
Насколько будет большая нагрузка на БД, если сделать это все через setInterval, например, с временем в 3 с? И вообще, как лучше поступить и в какую сторону двигать мысли?

Comment: лучше всего просто сделать приложение, которое при поступлении вопроса, будет сразу показывать его модератору, если через websockets то можно сделать на ноде или любом другом движке, который дружит с асинхронным кодом.

Comment: Думаю, что вопросы нужно перенести из базы в память, ибо так реально будет проще и быстрее (см. в сторону node.js). Ну и при завершении конференции, если уж сильно нужно, то сливать всю историю в БД. Ну а 300 запросов в час - это совсем ничего, другое - это сколько пользователей будет висеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант первый:

1. Добавляем в таблицу столбец, значение которого будет отвечать за модерацию, например: 1 - не модерировано, 2 - модерировано.
2. Выводим все промодерированные.

Вариант второй:

1. Создаём отдельную таблицу, куда будут отправляться записи до модерации, модераторам показываем записи оттуда - там они распоряжаются всем.
2. При модерации, например, если проходит - переносим в таблицу с проверенными вопросами.

А там уже аяксом подгружать модераторам, например.